# Python Django {% if usuario.username == user %} not work :(

Tags: python, django

I need some help.
I want to list all user avoid the login user.

if I print user= juan
if I print usuario.username=juan
There have the same string

```
{% if usuario.username == user %}
 Nothing
{% else %}
<tr><td>
{{usuario.username}}
<img src="{% static 'assets/img/icono_writeMSJ.png' %}"     height="30px">
</td>
</tr>
{% endif %}
```

if i change for example

```
{% if usuario.username == 'juan' %}
 Nothing
{% else %}
<tr><td>
{{usuario.username}}
<img src="{% static 'assets/img/icono_writeMSJ.png' %}"     height="30px">
</td>
</tr>
{% endif %}
```

this work fine, why?? :(

Comment: show model, views.

Answer (score 0):

user is an object. Stringify it. That should work

```
{% if usuario.username == user|stringformat:"s" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

======== excluded current logged-in user ========

```
========= in HTML ==============

<h3>All Users list</h3>

{% if  user.is_authenticated  %}
     <ul>
          {% for i in all_users %}
               <li>{{i.username}}</li>
          {% endfor %}
     </ul>
{% else %}
     <h4>Please login first</h4>


======= in views.py ===========

def HomeView(request):
    all_users = User.objects.all().exclude(id=request.user.id).values('username')
    return render(request,'index.html',{'all_users':all_users})
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the problem was that user is an objet. For that reason a can't compare from that way.

{% if usuario.username == user %}

the correct way is

{% if usuario.username == user.username %}